# Why relative url ./ to home page not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I modified my asp.net 2.0 website to be mobile friendly. On desktops and  tablets, the navigation menu is a horizontal bar styled with the class mobilemenu, and on all other devices it is a dropdown menu, styled with class mobiledropdown. Everything works except on mobile devices with the dropdown menu, the home page menu item does nothing when selected, but all the other dropdown items navigate correctly. In both cases the url for home page is "./" but I also tried hardcoding it with the full http://www plus my domain and that also works for mobilemenu but not mobiledropdown.

I am thinking it must be related to the javascript which is used only for the dropdown.
The code is below. it is contained in an include file. the css hides or shows the appropriate menu based on media queries and that all works great.
The first div element is for larger devices and is the code that has been used for several years without any issues. I added the mobilemenu class for hiding it on smaller devices. I added the second div for showing the dropdown on smaller devices.

```
<div class="mobilemenu"  style="width:90%; margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%; margin-top:0%; margin-bottom:1%; padding:0px;">
  <div id="menu" style="text-align:center;width:100%;height:22px; padding:0px;">
    <ul id="nav" style="line-height: 22px; width:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
      <li style="width:15%;">
        <a  class="custom" href="./">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li style="width:20%;">
        <a class="custom" href="Order.aspx" >Order</a>
      </li>
      <li style="width:15%;">
        <a class="custom" href="Company.aspx" >Company</a>
      </li>
      <li style="width:20%; ">
        <a class="custom" href="Download.aspx" >Downloads</a>
      </li>
      <li style="width:15%; ">
        <a class="custom" href="Blog.aspx" >Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="menu2" style="text-align:left">
    <select class="mobiledropdown"  onChange="window.location=this.value">
      <option value="./" selected="">Home</option>
      <option value="Support.aspx">Support</option>
      <option value="Order.aspx" >Order</option>
      <option value="Company.aspx" >Company</option>
      <option value="Download.aspx" >Downloads</option>
      <option value="Blog.aspx" >Blog</option>
    </select>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `../` instead?

Comment: Yes. that fires an error because the root is at the same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, although I do not understand why it works so maybe someone could explain.
I changed the html code for the dropdown menu by inserting a "Menu" option as the first option and removed the selected attribute on the Home option. It seems illogical that I have to add a menu item that I dont want.

```
  <div id="menu2" style="text-align:left">
    <select class="mobiledropdown"  onChange="window.location=this.value">
      <option>Menu</option>
      <option value="./">Home</option>
      <option value="Support.aspx">Support</option>
      <option value="Order.aspx" >Order</option>
      <option value="Company.aspx" >Company</option>
      <option value="Download.aspx" >Downloads</option>
      <option value="Blog.aspx" >Blog</option>
    </select>

  </div
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot (.):

```
 <select class="mobiledropdown"  onChange="window.location=this.value">
    <option value="/" selected="">Home</option>
    {rest of your code goes here}
 </select>
```

Comment: I tried that on one of our working sites, which is responsive similar to what you're doing, and it works just fine. Would be good if you try it on a clean page especially if you are working with a Master view. If it still doesn't work then try having a master view without any scripts running on it - isolation if your friend ;)

Comment: No master view. I test with an iPhone 5c and I can simulate on my desktop development machine by changing the media query to set the max-device-width from 640 to 2440 which results in showing the dropdown. Could this be a browser-specific issue?